# One method for one operation in OOP?

Tags: oop

In Functional Programming, the good rule of thumb for composition is to create a function for each operation and compose them together to achieve the desired functionality. 
In contrast, in Object-oriented Programming, should each method be self-contained with the use of less helper methods or same as Functional Programming? What is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Whether OOP or FP, a function should do one thing.

The good rule of thumb, no matter the paradigm is OOP or FP, is that [a function should do one thing](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop).

It does not mean that a function should not internally compose with others.

If helpers method contribute to participate to achieve the sole function/method responsibility, that's pretty fine to use them.